# Using VBA and Regex to grab cost from outlook email

Tags: regex, vba, email, outlook

I would like to grab the cost shown below as a number:
478150 or 478150.00

Net Cost Budget Amount: $478,150.00 - Current Baselined Version Number - 1 - Version Name - Net

The text is found in an outlook email body and I am trying to use VBA to grab this item.

```
With BDGT
   .Pattern = "(Net Cost Budget Amount[:] \d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+))\n"
   .Global = False
End With
```

Comment: Using Dot-Net in those vba regexes ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
.Pattern = "Net Cost Budget Amount\: \$((?:\d{1,3}\,\d{3}|\d{1,3})\.\d+)"
```

It will match any number between (and including) `0.00` and `999,999.99`, with mandatory separators.

I assume you already know how to extract matches/submatches with the vbscript.regex engine in VBA. If you don't, let me know.